# color breaks diacritics stacking

Tags: color

Assume one wants to use color on accents. For example black a with red acute (for example for stress in a linguistic text). If we load the color package, this code:

`a\color{red}́`

will not work with xelatex and a stacking capable font as NewComputerModern. It will work with lmmodern because there is no stacking mechanism there and the acute is an independent glyph in the negative(!) space.

I am interested in stacking diacritics. For example one may have to stack more than one diacritic.

I was informed by the developer of the color package that a solution is to go with the luacolor package and lualatex. This works partially:

If Harfbuzz is not loaded then one accent works. But if one has to load it with Renderer=Harfbuzz, because it may be needed to stack more than one character (and then lua needs Harfbuzz to work properly) then we have the following situation

(a) if the glyph to be composed with stacking does not exist in the font then all is fine. For example, this code:

`a\color{red}̐`

works.

(b) But if the glyph exists as a precomposed glyph in the font it fails. So this

`a\color{red}́`

fails because the font provides aacute as a precomposed glyph.

On the other hand

`a\color{red}̐\color{green}́`

works because there is no precomposed a̐

The question is if there is any idea of how to fix this. For example, is there any way to instruct the Renderer to NOT use the precomposed glyphs?

Unfortunately, precomposed glyphs can NOT be removed from NewCM (which would solve the issue too) since there are documents that type, say aacute directly.

Comment: I'm not saying you should remove the precomposed but I think if you do and the input has aacute that harfbuzz will decompose and use the combining accent on its own.

Comment: there is some discussion about glyph/glyph part coloring in https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2020-UFi-TUB-tb127fischer-bangla.pdf. Also you can tell luaotfload not to normalize with the RawFeature `-normalize` (but I didn't test if that helps in your case and I don't have not the time to do it.)

Comment: Checked -normalize. Does not help. However I found a workaround. There is a character in Unicode which is empty and called "Combining Grapheme Joiner". If this character is placed between the base glyph "a" and the first diacritic, lua is tricked and things work properly. It may not be the "correct" solution but it works. I have to document this in NewCM documentation. Thank you. I will also read the linked pdf you gave me carefully.

Comment: interesting, you could also make a small answer here if this is generally applicable, and not just something you support in newcm?

Comment: @Antonis Do you have an example where you need HarfBuzz for LuaLaTeX to work properly for stacked diacitics?

Comment: Sure. Try x́̀ without and with Renderer=Harfbuzz. Without it the second accent fails.(if the previous is unreadable, it is x followed by combining acute followed by combining grave).

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Old English poetry (long vowel + stress) could be an example; North American languages have many stacks - I'll try and track some down.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Antonis for finding the CGJ. All credit and points to him. Any errors, of interpretation and usage etc, are my own.

This is a footnote to the proper answer, and is about using an experimental feature of luaotfload to colour all occurances of a glyph in a particular font, including, by usage of the CGJ, the component glyphs of a composite glyph.

With a lua code colorscheme definition such as:

```
\directlua {
luaotfload.add_colorscheme("colaccxx", 
    {
        ["FF8000C0"] = {52},
        ["FF00FF"] = {131},
        ["FF0000"] = {"acutecomb"},
        ["00FF00"] = {36},
        ["00FFFF"] = {2881},
        ["0000FFF0"] = {193,"B","́"},
    })
}
```

assigned to a specific font declaration:

```
\newfontface\faccent{Noto Serif-Regular}[
Colour=colaccxx,
]
```

result is something like:

[image: example]

The colorscheme name (still experimental) is 8 characters with at least 1 non-Hex character. The left-hand side is an RRGGBBTT colour setting (red, green, blue, transparency; each from 00 to FF). The right-hand side is a font-specific list of names and/or glyph ID indices (e.g., `["name"]="uni0304",`, `["index"]=2886,`) taken from Lua's `.lua` font-cache file for the font.

Here, Noto Serif Regular font is used, so the cache file is `notoserif-regular.lua`. The cache folder is `...\texlive\2022\texmf-var\luatex-cache\generic\fonts\otl\`.

A typical entry looks like:

```
  [771]={
   ["boundingbox"]={ -496, 606, -140, 734 },
   ["class"]="mark",
   ["index"]=2885,
   ["name"]="tildecomb",
   ["unicode"]=771,
  },
```

The name and index values are font(version) specific. The Unicode codepoint value is decimal.

Example of use:

[image: usage]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\directlua {
luaotfload.add_colorscheme("colaccxx", 
    {
        ["FF8000C0"] = {52},
        ["FF00FF"] = {131},
        ["FF0000"] = {"acutecomb"},
        ["00FF00"] = {36},
        ["00FFFF"] = {2881},
        ["0000FFF0"] = {193,"B","́"},
    })
}


%       ["FF00FF"] = {118,"^^^^0301",2879,131},

\newfontface\faccent{Noto Serif-Regular}[
Colour=colaccxx,
]
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dov}{m}{{\ttfamily \c_circumflex_str\c_circumflex_str\c_circumflex_str\c_circumflex_str #1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\faccent
precomposed: ÁáÂâ
AaQB

combined: A^^^^034f^^^^0301a^^^^034f^^^^0301 A^^^^0301A\symbol{770}A\symbol{847}\symbol{770}a^^^^034f\symbol{770}
AaQB
C^^^^0302

\verb|notoserif-regular.lua|

\verb|...\texlive\2022\texmf-var\luatex-cache\generic\fonts\otl\|

\begin{verbatim}
  [180]={
   ["boundingbox"]=34,
   ["index"]=118,
   ["name"]="acute",
   ["unicode"]=180,
   ["width"]=274,
  },
\end{verbatim}


\begin{tblr}{
colspec={lllcc},
row{1}={bg={blue!12}},
row{2}={bg={yellow!5!red!8}},
row{3}={bg={yellow!1!red!2}},
row{Z}={font=\ttfamily\small},
}
glyph 
& name 
& index 
& w/o CGJ 
& with CGJ 
\\\hline
65 {\\} 769     
& "A"{\\}"acutecomb" ( ^^^^0301)    
& 36 {\\} 2879 ( ^^^^0301)   
&  ^^^^0041^^^^0301 {\\}  \dov{0041}\dov{0301}
& ^^^^0041^^^^034f^^^^0301 {\\}  \dov{0041}\dov{034f}\dov{0301}
\\
65 {\\} 770     
& "A"{\\} "uni0302" ( ^^^^0302)    
& 36 {\\} 2881 ( ^^^^0302)    
&  ^^^^0041^^^^0302 {\\}  \dov{0041}\dov{0302}
& ^^^^0041^^^^034f^^^^0302 {\\}  \dov{0041}\dov{034f}\dov{0302}
\\\hline
decimal
& text
& decimal
& hex
& hex
\\ 
\end{tblr}

\begin{verbatim}
\directlua {
luaotfload.add_colorscheme("colaccxx", 
    {
        ["FF8000C0"] = {52},
        ["FF00FF"] = {131},
        ["FF0000"] = {"acutecomb",2881},
        ["00FF00"] = {36},
        ["00FFFF"] = {"^^^^0302"},
        ["0000FFF0"] = {193,"B","́"},
    })
}
\end{verbatim}


\begin{verbatim}
\newfontface\faccent{Noto Serif-Regular}[
Colour=colaccxx,
]
\end{verbatim}


\begin{tblr}{
colspec={lX[l]},
row{1}={bg={blue!12}},
column{Z}={font=\ttfamily\small},
}
glyphs 
& code input 
\\
áááâââ
& áááâââ
\\
á^^^^034fááâââ
& á\dov{034f}ááâââ
\\
a^^^^034f^^^^0301ááâââ
& a\dov{034f}\dov{0301}ááâââ
\\
a^^^^034f^^^^0301a^^^^0301a^^^^0301a^^^^0302ââ
& a\dov{034f}\dov{0301}a\dov{0301}a\dov{0301}a\dov{0302}ââ
\\
\end{tblr}


\end{document}
```

^-notation is used for convenience, rather than direct input, to make the marks more visible in the code.

Comment: Ref: colorscheme: texdoc luaotfload, p 14.

Comment: Many compliments for your 10k of reputation. +1

Comment: So just to clarify things... your example does use CGJ to color accents with a base of different colors. Right? You do not escape this at the moment. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: If a colour is specified, the `Colour=` or `Color=` option will apply the colour to all glyphs in the font, e.g., `Colour=red`'. If a colorscheme is specified instead, glyphs will be coloured according to the scheme.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the work around I described above works with other fonts too. I check for example with NotoSerif-Regular. I post below this answer with an example as screenshot from the upcoming documentation of NewCM. The reason I prefer the screenshot is to be able to see the diacritics more clearly.

[image]